# Prevent Powershell close on Shutdown

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I have a Script to execute a code at shutdown but the code don't get executed because Windows closes the Powershell session.

Is there a way to prevent Powershell from closing if you press shutdown Windows?

To track the shutdown I use:

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $sysevent -EventName "SessionEnding" -Action { [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Shutdown!", "", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning)}

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $sysevent -EventName "SessionEnded" -Action { [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Shutdown!", "", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning)}
```

**Edit:**
I have a Script that runs in the background. This script is used to activate a product on a Server. If the user shutdown the pc, the script should deactivate the product on a server.

Situation now: Script run normal, product is activated on server. After on shutdown the script closes and do nothing

Situation expected: Script run normal, product is activated on server. After on shutdown the script runs last command and then shutdown the machine

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need this for?

Comment: relying on a user/client machine to perform server behavior is a bad approach

Comment: What Ctznkane525 said. However, if you absolutely must do this, try running a [shutdown script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771106(v=ws.11)).